# Updating Sequential values

Tags: t-sql, sql-update

I have a table with ID and sequence # (SEQ) starting number. I want to update SQ number for each ID based on the SEQ

My table like this

```
ID       SQ    SEQ
---      --    ---
100      0      11
100      0      11
100      0      11
200      0      13
200      0      13
200      0      13
200      0      13
```

I want to get result table like this:

```
ID     | SQ | SEQ

100      11      11
100      12      11
100      13      11
200      13      13
200      14      13
200      15      13
200      16      13
```

How can I do this using TSQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
select id,(ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by id order by id) + seq - 1) as sqn,seq from @tbl
```

Complete sample code with test data

```
declare @tbl table(id int, sq int, seq int)
insert into @tbl
select 100,0,11 union all
select 100,0,11 union all
select 100,0,11 union all
select 200,0,13 union all
select 200,0,13 union all
select 200,0,13 union all
select 200,0,13 

select id,(ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by id order by id) + seq - 1) as sqn,seq from @tbl
```

Result

```
id  sqn seq
100 11  11
100 12  11
100 13  11
200 13  13
200 14  13
200 15  13
200 16  13
```

Answer (score 0):

try it's.

```
SELECT 
ID,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ID ) AS SQ,SEQ
FROM YOUR_TABLE
```

And for update, use it's

```
 update a set sq = rn
    ID,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ID ) AS rn,SEQ
    FROM YOUR_TABLE) as a
```